# Power of Brightness in a Color

Tags: visible-light

I want to compare yellow color, as a mixture of red & green in RGB. So basically I will put a shape inside a background and will switch the shape every 1 second. My hypothesis was I wouldn't be able to recognize the shape since they're the same value as the background. But in fact, I still can recognize the shape because after switching the shape, its brightness won't be constant anymore, like the illustration below.

[image]

In order to compensate this, my plan is to set the shape brightness as a twice of the background. So, I need this final mixture color of red-green to have twice brightness as the original red-green color so they're equal. I know I can convert the color into another color space, or using Photoshop and directly access the Brightness value.

In this case I'm not allowed to use the brightness parameter and only need to modify the RGB value. This is what I've done so far (picture), is it wise enough to do it this way ?? Is there another better way to achieve this goal ? By doing this, will this achieve twice as power of brightness as the background ?

[image]

Comment: RBG values (0=>255) is not related to brightness of the light source, it's entirely for color calibration (light yellow vs dirty yellow).

Comment: @Melvin I'm aware of it, RGB doesn't encode brightness information. So, this approach isn't right in this case ? Do you have any other advice ?

Comment: Do you have images (in an electronic form) as your input, or do you have access to the setup directly?

Comment: @Melvin I have electronic images as my input.

Comment: So if I may clarify, you want some form of calibration algorithm such that it'll result in all images being the same (without knowing beforehand), for the same colour scheme with different objects. You'll have to first verify that the camera isn't applying different iso or aperture settings or that the detector isn't being washed out (so the image file data is a precise representation).

Comment: Next, I'm going to suggest that your question is identical to a situation of someone taking an image of a light source, with different aperture sizes. Having objects block the source of light is equivalent to that of using different apertures to take photos of the same light source. You might want to change your question then, to how one can normalise the brightness of an image, when it is taken of a light source but with different aperture sizes, other things being equal. Searching along these lines should provide you with a decent existing image processing algorithm. :)

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to avoid tackling your problem head-on, is because it requires understanding about things like your camera's gamma curve, and any post processing done by your camera (unless you're shooting in raw). I'm pretty sure that the aperture size brightness correction is a solved problem, so there's no need to reinvent the wheel (assuming that you'll be able to adapt the solution for that to what you need).

Comment: @Melvin Thanks, it's hard for me to grasp your explanation because I'm not using any camera. It's exactly as I explain above, I will put a background and switching shape. I will put both of digital (electronic) images as an input of a program and will be displayed at screen. And we will observe using naked eyes. I need some advice if my approach is decent enough, or if someone has any better idea for this case.